# How to easily link database model with view model and server model in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, rest, mapping

I'm new to C# and I wonder if there is an easy way to map a database model to domain model to server model ? Each model represents the same object but is different in term of properties.

I'm trying to develop a simple UWP application for Windows 10 (mobile and desktop) using Trakt.tv API. It is just for my learning process. I'll not publish the application on the store.

I'm thinking about a class which will retrieve from the database if need but also from the web server, be used by the view, save all modification to the database also to the web server if needed.

Any idea how I can achieve that ?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using ASP.net mvc or what ?

Comment: Developing an UWP application for Windows 10 (Mobile/Desktop)